# 'Unable to connect to the remote server' when connected to corporate intranet

Tags: httpwebrequest

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.bbc.co.uk");

string stream;

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Default))
{
   stream = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

If I'm connected to a corporate intranet I get "Unable to connect to the remote server". When I'm not connected it connects fine. Why might this be?

(The intranet is not the BBC's. That's just a random URL I picked.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked up one of the proxies that IE is using and used that. It worked!